# Cursor jumping to wrong place on Editor view

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am writing a simple application using C# and Xamarin.Forms library via a PCL project. The application uses an Editor view, detects input '~' (tilde) characters. The '~' character is replaced by a '|' character using the TextChanged event of the Editor view.

The problem is: after the Text property of the Editor view is updated (please see below codes), the cursor on the Editor view jumps to the very beginning position of the Editor instead of staying right after the lastly-typed-in character on the Editor's surface. To continue typing, I have to move the cursor right after the lastly-input character's position . Anytime, a tilde '~' is detected, the behind update logic is executed, and the cursor  on the Editor view AGAIN jumps to the very beginning position of the Editor. Moving it beyond the lastly-input character's position of the Editor is a must for users.  This bug is annoying to me.

How can I solve the bug for the cursor? I'd like it to stay right after the lastly-typed-in character on the Editor's surface so I do not need to move it whenever a tilde '~' is detected.

The code-behind logic:

```
public void OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var editor = (Editor)sender;
   if(editor.Text.Contains("~"))
   {
     editor.Text = editor.Text.Replace("~", "|"); // updated the Text of Editor
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in the latest version (2.3.x). https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/EditorRenderer.cs#L111

Just update it via NuGet.

Comment: thank you very much. The latest version solves the problem/

Comment: seems like still a problem in 2.3.4.247
am I the only one?